# Kubernetes - ScaledObject - Keda - RabbitMQ

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, keda, horizontalpodautoscaler

i have created a ScaledObject and TriggerAuthentication using Keda, in order to horizontally autoscale my pods based on a RabbitMQ length.

but for some reason, when i try to query my ScaledObjects like this:

```
kubectl get ScaledObjects -n mynamespace
```

i am not getting anything.
but when i am applying the yaml file which contains all of the information about the ScaledObject, the output is this:

```
scaledobject.keda.sh/rabbitmq-scaledobject unchanged
```

i am also able to edit this scaled object using this command:

```
kubectl edit scaledobject.keda.sh/rabbitmq-scaledobject -n mynamespace
```

but i am not sure why it is not listed when doing this command:

```
kubectl get ScaledObjects -n mynamespace
```

the autoscaler does work, i am just wondering why it is not listed..

Thanks in Advance,
Yaniv

Comment: How about `kubectl get scaledobject.keda.sh/rabbitmq-scaledobject -n mynamespace`?

Comment: @ToddHolmberg this works as well, but not sure why i don't see it as part of the list when trying to do:
`kubectl get ScaledObjects -n mynamespace`

Comment: Installed `keda v2.5.0` on `minikube`, created a `scaledobject` and can see it with `kubectl get scaledobjects` command. What versions of `keda` and `kubectl` are used?

Comment: am also using keda v2.5.0, kubectl version gives me this output:

`Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.4", GitCommit:"b695d79d4f967c403a96986f1750a35eb75e75f1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-11-17T15:48:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.9", GitCommit:"a5e4de7e277a707bd28d448bd75de58b4f1cdc22", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-11-16T01:09:55Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.14", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`
@moonkotte

Comment: Which kubernetes platform is used? Like minikube or managed in cloud? To try to reproduce it exactly.

Comment: @moonkotte using AKS

Answer (score 0):

This might be a case of having more than one Custom Resource defined with the same `kind` but a different `apiVersion`.

For example, these two versions of Keda create the `ScaledObject` with different `apiVersion`:

- 1.4:

```yaml
apiVersion: keda.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
```

- 2.0:

```yaml
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
```

So when you run `kubectl get ScaledObjects -n mynamespace`, it might be defaulting to the one you are not using.